# Jackson JSON XML - different names when serializing to XML

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I'd like to have different name for my element when it's serialized to XML (for example "`fooXml`") and different for JSON (for example "`fooJson`"). Is it possible?

I'm using XML annotations like:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(type = Foo.class, name = "fooXml"),
    })
    private SortedSet<Foo> fooSet;
```

I've tried already `@JsonProperty`, with without any luck.

I've also tried exporting it to getter method, like:

```
@XmlElement(type = Foo.class, name = "fooXml")
@JsonProperty(value = "fooJson")
public List<Foo> getFooList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(fooSet);
}
```

But it's always ignoring JSON annotations and serializing to XML form (`fooXml` name).

How shall I do it?

edit: I'm using Jersey-json.

Comment: Is it serializing to XML and not at all to json or just to json and uses the XML name?

Comment: @Feroc JSON uses XML name.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I had a need for this same functionality and found a solution that works for this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

@JsonProperty("MyJsonName")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyXmlName")
private MyProperty myProperty;
```

Works for me, and myProperty will be in the 'MyJsonName' field in Json and the 'MyXmlName' in XML.